# How to sort an array by entry indexes?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to sort INDEXES of an array that contains double values. The sorting should be made in ascending order. I do this in the following way (see below). It works fine if an array contains integer values, but it stops working with double values. Why? Please notice that I am sorting the Indexes, not the values of an array.

The result should be `[1,0]`, which refers to `[893.05,1129.25]`.

```
double[] times = new double[2];

times[0] = 1129.25;
times[1] = 893.05;

ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(times,0);
Integer[] sortedTimes = comparator.createIndexArray();
Arrays.sort(sortedTimes, comparator);

public class ArrayIndexComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    private double[] array;
    private int sort;

    public ArrayIndexComparator(double[] array, int sort)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public Integer[] createIndexArray()
    {
        Integer[] indexes = new Integer[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            indexes[i] = i;
        }
        return indexes;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer index1, Integer index2)
    {
        if (sort == 0)
            return Double.compare(array[index2],array[index1]); // descending order ...2,1,0
        else
            return Double.compare(array[index1],array[index2]); // ascending order 0,1,2,...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `compare` method of your custom comparator, you are sorting in descending order since you have the `sort` field set to `0` in the call to your constructor.

Just replace the `0` with any other number in `ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(times,0);`

e.g. `ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(times,1);`

Comment: I did this. The content of sortedTimes is absolutely the same: [0,1], which refers to [1129.25,893.05]. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I don't get it, the ordering is different for asc and desc so where's the problem?

Comment: If I run ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(times,1);, then the result is the same to ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(times,0);

Comment: How are you printing the results?

Comment: times[sortedTimes[i]]

Comment: I am sorry, it was debugging problem. I restarted the debugging process and now the program give correct results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn;t fully understand what you said but I got the result you wanted only modifying the compare function

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer index1, Integer index2)
    {

        if (index1<index2){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (index1>index2){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
     }
```

Comment: I must compare the values of an array, not the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(times,1);
```

Using above ( passing 1 to instruct to sort ascending) , i am getting proper values in ascending order.

Test Code

```
    for(Integer op : sortedTimes)
    {
        System.out.println(times[op]);
    }
```

Output

```
893.05
1129.25
```